# TCP client for Unity

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

How to write a TCP client in Unity3d which reads data constantly from a server socket and prints to the console or updates on some text boxes?

Comment: What platform are you developing for? If you have the Pro version of Unity you should be able to use the System.Net.Socket class.

Comment: @calvin:: I dont have any experience with unity, I have downloaded the unity3d, i assume its the free version, in which i  and am trying to achieve this:: I have data flowing from kinect to server written in nodejs and i want the client in unity3d to read the data from the server.

Comment: Have you seen this thread?: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/67982-Kinect-plugin  I don't think Sockets are available in the free version of Unity. You might be able to get the data from node.js by pulling 1 frame of data using the WWW class every frame.  Or you could have node write the data to a file and read from that file in Unity.

Comment: Sockets may only be disabled in Unity iPhone/iOS. Their product matrix is getting confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a TCP client in unity3d is nearly the same as developing it in c#, you can use almost all the classes of .net (4.0 as of the latest unity 3.5), still before you use a class look for the support in mono from [this](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility) page.

If the class is not supported in mono, just drag the respected dll corresponding to the class from the .net library.  Also you have two methods to do it, write the whole logic using .net classes in unity.  or  make a dll of it and import it into unity and use that dll for processing TCP works.   In terms of performance there is no difference, all depends on ur preference.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good starting point:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/15422/unity-project-and-3rd-party-apps.html